# Does the non-intrusive method for serialising a class in Boost::Serialise make the class serializable?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm trying to understand Boost's serialization library [(see tutorial)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html) and quite like the non-intrusive way of serialising a class because it means I can put all of my serialization code in separate files:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

class gps_position
{
public:
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
    gps_position(){};
    gps_position(int d, int m, float s) :
        degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s)
    {}
};

namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, gps_position & g, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & g.degrees;
    ar & g.minutes;
    ar & g.seconds;
}

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

While this method provides a function 'serialise', which can be used to serialize the 'gps_position' class, I am not sure whether the class is itself *serializable* (ie. acts like a primitive in terms of serializing/deserializing) once this function has been created, or if I have to use the intrusive method for that...

That is, if I have another class which contains, say, a vector of 'gps_position' instances, will Boost know to look for the overloaded 'serialize' function in the Boost::serialization namespace matching a 'gps_position' parameter when I try to serialize the parent class? Or would it only look explicitly for a 'serialize' method of the class (which it wouldn't find in this instance)?

I couldn't find the answer to this question in the tutorials and was hoping someone with experience using this library might be able to shed some light!

P.S I'm reluctant to "just try it" because I don't know what failure should look like (will Boost just serialize "something"?)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> While this method provides a function 'serialise', which can be used
>   to serialize the 'gps_position' class, I am not sure whether the class
>   is itself serializable (ie. acts like a primitive in terms of
>   serializing/deserializing) once this function has been created, or if
>   I have to use the intrusive method for that...

Yes the class will be serializable through the normal method of using the '&' operator with a boost.serialization archive, regardless of which method you use.

> That is, if I have another class which contains, say, a vector of
>   'gps_position' instances, will Boost know to look for the overloaded
>   'serialize' function in the Boost::serialization namespace matching a
>   'gps_position' parameter when I try to serialize the parent class? Or
>   would it only look explicitly for a 'serialize' method of the class
>   (which it wouldn't find in this instance)?

You will need to also provide a serialization function for the parent class. In which you will serialize each member of the class in much the same way as you will have done the child class.

> P.S I'm reluctant to "just try it" because I don't know what failure
>   should look like (will Boost just serialize "something"?)...

Just trying it, is the best possible way you could have learned. It's most likely that this is how anyone else looking to answer this question will have learnt after a brief look at the docs.

Here's a very quick mockup of both the intrusive and non-instrusive versions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

// child class serialized using intrusive

struct child
{
  std::string name;

  child() = default;

  explicit child(const std::string& name)
    : name(name)
  { }

  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int /* version */)
  {
    ar & name;
  }
};


struct parent
{
  std::vector<child> children;

  parent() = default;

  explicit parent(const std::vector<child>& children)
    : children(children)
  { }
};

// parent class serialized using non-instrusive

namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template <class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, parent& p, const unsigned int /* version */)
{
  ar & p.children;
}

}
}

int main()
{
  parent p1 {{child("one"), child("two"), child("three")}};

  std::stringstream ss;
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
  oa << p1;

  parent p2;
  boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
  ia >> p2;

  for (auto& child : p2.children) {
    std::cout << child.name << "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> While this method provides a function 'serialise', which can be used to serialize the 'gps_position' class, I am not sure whether the class is itself serializable (ie. acts like a primitive in terms of serializing/deserializing) once this function has been created, or if I have to use the intrusive method for that...

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) says:

> A type `T` is **Serializable** if and only if one of the following is true:
>
> - it is a primitive type. [...]
> - It is a class type and one of the following has been declared according to the prototypes detailed below:
>
>   - a class member function `serialize`
>   - a global function `serialize`
> - it is a pointer to a **Serializable** type.
> - it is a reference to a **Serializable** type.
> - it is a native C++ Array of **Serializable** type.

---

> That is, if I have another class which contains, say, a vector of 'gps_position' instances, will Boost know to look for the overloaded 'serialize' function in the Boost::serialization namespace matching a 'gps_position' parameter when I try to serialize the parent class? Or would it only look explicitly for a 'serialize' method of the class (which it wouldn't find in this instance)?

A class type for which no member function `serialize` and no global function `serialize` is defined (the latter having a non-const ref of the class type as second parameter) does not fulfil the **Serializable** concept.

However, on same page of the documentation:

> The facilities described above are sufficient to implement serialization for all STL containers. In fact, this has been done and has been included in the library.

That is, if you include the appropriate header file, `<boost/serialization/vector.hpp>`, a specialization of the vector template becomes **Serializable** iff its `value_type` is **Serializable**.

As your class `gps_position` is **Serializable**, a `std::vector<gps_position>` is also **Serializable** if you included the aforementioned header. However, a class containing such a vector isn't automatically **Serializable** itself according to the rules. It needed to have a member or non-member function `serialize`:

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
struct gps_position { int i; };
struct gps_path { std::vector<gps_position> v; }

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, gps_position& p, const unsigned int)
{  ar & p.i;  }
// by declaring this function, `gps_position` is Serializable

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, gps_path& p, const unsigned int)
{  ar & p.v;  }
// as `v` is Serializable (because `gps_position` is Serializable),
// you can leave it to the boost library to serialize the individual
// elements of the vector
```

---

Note: the function does not have to be global. As explained on the linked page of the documentation, both unqualified lookup and ADL are supported:

> For maximum portability, include any free functions templates and definitions in the namespace `boost::serialization`. If portability is not a concern and the compiler being used supports ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup) the free functions and templates can be in any of the following namespaces:
>
> - `boost::serialization`
> - namespace of the archive class
> - namespace of the type being serialized

Comment: In my case I *have* declared a global serialize function though, so the concept is satisfied, right?

Comment: @ausairman You have declared a free function `serialize` in namespace `boost::serialization` (it isn't global) for the class `gps_position`, so this class `gps_position` fulfils the **Serializable** concept. Any other class, e.g. a derived class or a class with a member of type `gps_position`, needs its own member or non-member function `serialize` to fulfil the **Serializable** concept.

Comment: Right I see the confusion; my question was about the gps_position class, not any other classes. Ie. I wanted to know whether the gps_position was serializable.